# UWP How to get the custom item clicked in a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, click

I've a grid view with a custom control  item as following. The items are UserControll of type StaticResource:UserControlCataloghiTematici.

```
<GridView SizeChanged="listView_SizeChanged" 
              x:Name="listView"  
              Background="#fff"
              Margin="0,50,10,0" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemClick="listView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="4" 
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=griglia}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ImageTextDataTemplate" >
                <StaticResource:UserControlCataloghiTematici  Height="auto" Width="auto"   >
                </StaticResource:UserControlCataloghiTematici>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Because sender in the event is the GridView, is there a way to get back the UserControl clicked in listView_ItemClick event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `ContainerFromItem` method of `GridView` to retrieve the `GridViewItem`element that wraps your template contents. Then you can use `VisualTreeHelper` to locate the user control by its type.

```
var gridViewItem = MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
var control = gridViewItem.FindDescendant<UserControlCataloghiTematici>() ;
```

This requires you to use [`VisualTreeExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree#api) from the UWP Community Toolkit which you can get on NuGet.